# What openGL package am I missing?

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I am trying to resurrect on old OpenGL program on a Linux Mint system. I installed freeglut3-dev using Synaptic Package Manager. The compiler does not complain about not being able to find the glut include file anymore, but now I have other problems:

```
cc -Wall -o gears main.c draw_gears.c gl_drawing.c load_data.c normal.c prep_data.c -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfNsT0O.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glNewList'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gears] Error 1
```

Comment: Please look at the formatting options and edit and format your question.

Comment: It looks like your linker can't find the library. So it complains about a function whose definition it couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cc -Wall -o gears main.c draw_gears.c gl_drawing.c load_data.c normal.c prep_data.c -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

Comment: That did it. That and the math library (-lm). And the program still runs!

Comment: No. Adding the three libraries was all it took.